# Angular using RxJS - How to map data when JSON object has multiple properties

Tags: json, angular, rxjs

My code initially worked until I needed to change the structure of my JSON object. This is my original JSON object structure, it is just a simple list of products returned by my API.  I am abbreviating for brevity:

```
[{"PicFile":"11382","ShortDesc":"At Home Slot Machine","ActualPrice":12.99, .... }]
```

In my products service, I call my API and return a the list converted to my product model:

```
getProductsByCategory(categoryCode: string): Observable<Product[]> {
let url = this.baseAPIUrl + .....
return this.httpClient.get(url)
       .pipe(
         map((data: any[]) => data.map((item) => this.adapter.convert(item)))
     );
}
```

This is my adapter code.  I created a generic adapter that can take in any type of object, this is it's implementation:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Adapter } from "./adapter";

export class Product {
    constructor(
        public PicFile: string,
        public ShortDesc: string,
        public ActualPrice: number,
        .... other properties here

    ) { }
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
})
export class ProductAdapter implements Adapter<Product> {
    convert(item: any): Product {   
        return new Product(item.PicFile, item.ShortDesc, item.ActualPrice, .... );
    }
}
```

In my products component, I am subscribing to the observable returned from the service:

```
 loadAllProductsByCategory(categoryCode: string) {
        this.loadingSubject.next(true);

        this.productService.getProductsByCategory(categoryCode).pipe(
            catchError(() => of([])),
            finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
        )
            .subscribe(products => this.productsSubject.next(products));
    }
```

This works perfectly with my simple JSON structure.  I needed to add a count property for paging purposes and will most likely be adding others in the future.  The new JSON object has a property of "Data" that holds the list of products, and a property called "Count".

```
{"Data":[{"PicFile":"11382","ShortDesc":"At Home Slot Machine","ActualPrice":12.99, ...}], "Count":41}
```

So, my question is how do I change my service code to look for the "Data" property and convert it?:

```
return this.httpClient.get(url)
       .pipe(
         map((data: any[]) => data.map((item) => this.adapter.convert(item))) <-- how to look for "Data" property and convert only that list, not the whole object?
     );
```

I have tried several things, including subscribing here but then it is converted to a subscription and I need to return the observable.  I'm sure it can be done, hopefully, but I am fairly new to Angular and RxJS.  I just can't seem to figure out the mapping syntax correctly.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide,
Jim

Comment: I don't understand why you have an adapter, when you could just subscribe to the API and expect a Product.

Comment: Try `map((data: any) => data['Data'].map((item) => this.adapter.convert(item)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the structure of your data returned has changed, you need to update your `map` in the service.

```
 return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(
    map( (data: any) => data.Data.map((item) => this.adapter.convert(item)) )
);
```

you should probably changed the property name you pass into your map to avoid confusion. i.e.

```
(resp: any) => resp.Data.map((item) => this.adapter.convert(item))
```

The structure of the data returned from the service has changed from and Array to an Object. therefore, you must change your mapping process

this updated code will only return the `Data` array from your response.

if you need to also return the count, then you will need to update your service method `getProductsByCategory` to return an object that includes the count as well as the data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and accurate response.  I did take your advice and changed the "Data" property name.  It is working perfectly now.

You bring up a good point that I will need to access the count property and probably others I will add.  Can you give some insight on what I would need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the lines of this:

```
return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(
  map((response: any) => {
    response.data=response.data.map((item) => this.adapter.convert(item));
    return response;
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A common mapping pattern when getting JSON from a service is to create or enrich an object with data from the response

```
 return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(
    map(response => ({
      ProcessingTimeStamp: Date.now(),
      fullName: `${response.productName} (${response.productShortHand})`,
      count: response.count,
      data: response.Data.map(item => this.adapter.convert(item)),
      foo: response.bar,
      message: `I can sell you ${count}, of ${response.productShortHand} for cheap! Buy from me!`
    }))
);
```

This pattern turns a response into an object you can consume later however you like. Here a response is turned into an object with the form:

```
{
  ProcessingTimeStamp: number,
  fullName: string,
  count: number,
  data: item[],
  foo: any,
  message: string
}
```

You're really not limited with what you can do. If it works with TS/JS, you can do it. You can shove functions or nested observables, ect.

Comment: thank you for your post and explanation.  I am getting some syntax errors in trying to implement your code. I get "Propery 'count' does not exist on Type Object" and the same thing for "Data".  Here is the code I am trying:
```
  getProductsByCategoryNEW(categoryCode: string): Observable<object> {
  ... your code here... 
Am I specifying my return type incorrectl?

@Mrk Sef

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular Cli 16 with HttpClient of RxJS.

I found easy the solution to get array of MyObject casted by service and then manage them...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MyObject } from './myobject';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyObjectService {

  constructor(private _http : HttpClient){ }
  
  readProducts(): Observable<MyObject[]>{
    return this._http.get<MyObject[]>("http://mydomain/path/to/apy/");
          
  }
}
```

Once you have your array you can manage objects as you like.

HttpClient already get json object if it is specified by Content-Type server side.